# Date validation in ruby not working for the 'year'

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I have the below code to verify the dates are in correct format and in range. I cna't figure out why year is not validated properly.

```rb
def valid_date?(date)
  DateTime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  true
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end

puts valid_date?("202-02-20 00:00:00").inspect # ❌ returns true. But this is wrong. Year shouldn't be 202.
puts valid_date?("2020/02/20 00:59:00").inspect # ✅ false. This is correct behavior. 
puts valid_date?("2020-02-31 00:00:00").inspect # ✅ returns false. This is correct behavior. Date for Feb cannot be 31.
puts valid_date?("2020-02-20 24:00:00").inspect # ✅ true. This is correct behavior. 
puts valid_date?("2020-02-20 00:00:00").inspect # ✅ true. This is correct behavior.
puts valid_date?("2020-02-20 25:00:00").inspect # ✅ false. This is correct behavior.
puts valid_date?("2020-02-20 00:59:00").inspect # ✅ true. This is correct behavior.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use a different approach to validating dates for your purposes.  The fact is that `strptime` will recognize *any* integer value as a valid year, and will similarly recognize other values (month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds) without requiring the specific number of digits.  Consider the following example:

```
DateTime.strptime("0-1-1 0:0:0", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#=>  0000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

...and when applied to your code:

```
valid_date?("0-1-1 0:0:0")
#=>  true
```

Comment: Agreed with this answer. My suggestion is checking for a valid date, then converting, then checking if the year is within your expected range. I imagine that someone working on a history project for Egyptians would be happy with this outcome

Comment: `strptime` %Y will accept negative years as well.

Comment: Try  and "1582-10-15 00:00:00" and "1582-10-14 00:00:00". `true` for the first, `false` for the second.

Comment: @steenslag ["A Date object can be created with an optional argument, the day of calendar reform as a Julian day number...  The default value is Date::ITALY (2299161=1582-10-15)"](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#class-Date-label-Date) In certain countries, like Italy, Oct 14th, 1582 does not exist due to [the transition from the Julian to Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar#Adoption_in_Catholic_countries).

Comment: Thank you @Schwern.  I made a correction to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`%Y`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) is simply "year with century" and can even be negative. The "4 digits at least" does not seem to be true for parsing, only formatting.

> ```
> %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
>      -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
> ```

```
# 0002-02-20T00:59:00+00:00
puts DateTime.strptime("2-02-20 00:59:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You'll need to add any arbitrary extra constraints on the date. For example, if you only want year 2000 or sooner...

```
require 'date'

def valid_date?(input)
  date = DateTime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  date.year >= 2000
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end
```